# Write to AppGroup shared directory

Tags: objective-c, ios-app-group

I try to write to the AppGroup shared container with the following Ojecttive-C code:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
NSURL *path = [fileManager 
   containerURLForSecurityApplicationsGroupIdentifier:@"group.*myGroupIdentifier*"]; 
NSString *vtPath = [path.absoluteString stringByAppendingPathComponent:*fileName*]; 
[fileManager createFileAtPath:vtPath contents:nil attributes:nil]; 
NSFileHandle *vtData = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingPath: vtPath];
```

At this point vtData is always nil, so I can't write there.

The Path with appended fileName looks like
@"file:///Users/***/Library/Developer ... /data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/ ... /Library/filename.dat"

I have not found a solution after searching for hours. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Tip: use URLs instead of paths.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the URL I got back: It startet with "file:///".

After converting to a path, it started with "file:/"

After removing the "file:" at the beginning it works now.